# Becoming a Perl bandit

Tags: perl, ssh

I've posted a few questions about *natas* a wargame. But I'm stuck at *natas29* it has to do with Perl. I've never coded in Perl before.

Thus to help me beat the last few levels, I decided it is time to learn Perl. And what better way to learn it, then with wargames from [overthewire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/). I made a small Perl program that beats the first few levels of bandit (in combination with some bash commands)

I'm specifically looking for answers that provide insights on how certain Perl operation could be abused, but *any* review is welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSH::Perl;

my ($hostname, $username, $password, $port, $command) = ("bandit.labs.overthewire.org", "bandit0", "bandit0", "2220", "");

sub next_level {
    my ($user) = @_;
    $user =~ s/(\d+)\z/ $1 + 1 /e;
    return $user;
}

sub bandit_level {
    my ($pass, $user, $c) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", port=>$port, debug=>0);
    $ssh->login("$user","$pass");
    my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("$c");
    my $new_pass = $stdout;
    return $new_pass;
}

sub read_file {
    my %hash;
    open CONFIG, "commands.txt" or die;
    while (my $line = <CONFIG>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($lvl, $cmd) = split /\:/, $line;
        $hash{$lvl} = $cmd;
    }
    close CONFIG;
    return %hash;
}

my %hash = read_file;
my $bandit_count = scalar(keys %hash);

while ($bandit_count-- > 0)
{
    print "$username:$password\n";
    $command = $hash{$username};
    $password = bandit_level($password, $username, "$command");
    chomp $password;
    $password =~ s/\s//g;
    $username = next_level($username);
}
```

With `commands.txt` being this:

```
bandit0:cat readme
bandit1:cat ./-
bandit2:cat 'spaces in this filename'
bandit3:cat inhere/.hidden
bandit4:cat inhere/./-file07
bandit5:cat inhere/./maybehere07/.file2
bandit6:cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/bandit7.password
bandit7:cat data.txt | grep millionth | sed -e 's/^millionth//'
bandit8:cat data.txt | sort | uniq -u
bandit9:strings data.txt | grep '=' | cut -d '=' -f11 | tail -c 36
bandit10:base64 -d data.txt
```

*Not yet another perl hacker ;)*

Comment: I don't really understand what you are expecting from us. I can give you a code review and tell you about style in your code. There are a few things that can be improved, where you're not adhering to best practices and such. Do you want those?

Comment: @simbabque Yes! That is exactly what I want. Sorry if it is not worded properly. I mean to learn about common perl pitfalls

Comment: Okay but which is it, a code review or common Perl pitfalls (like spelling it with a small `p`)?

Comment: @Borodin Any and all. I'm starting to enjoy *Perl* and want to gobble up as much information possible.

Comment: I don't think Code Review is a good place for the latter, except insofar as it relates to the specific code you have shown in your question. I've added a couple comments to **simbabque's** excellent answer. To elaborate on the spelling, `Perl` is the language while `perl` is the compiler/interpreter executable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is going to talk about your style, and best practices. Some of it may be subjective. I'll go through the code line by line.

> ```
> use strict;
> use warnings;
> ```

Good job! Modern Perl programs should always start with `strict` and `warnings`. If you want more detailed information on what's wrong, you can add [`use diagnostics`](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html), but remember to remove it before you ship, because it is really heavy and just a debugging aid. You can also turn on `use warnings 'all'`.

---

> ```
> my ($hostname, $username, $password, $port, $command) = ("bandit.labs.overthewire.org", "bandit0", "bandit0", "2220", "");
> ```

As you can see from the scrollbar, this line is long. For two or three variables, assigning them as a list is fine, but in this case, I would break them into five statements. It's way clearer, especially since `$username` and `$password` have the same value.

In addition, you do not need to put numbers into quotes, unless you need a leading zero (i.e. for a ZIP, ISBN or EAN code).

Some people prefer single quotes `''` when there is no [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Perl), but that really doesn't matter and is a question of personal preference. For the empty string, I prefer to use [`q{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html), as that clear shows the intention of an empty string, over a forgotten string or a typo that made it to production, because of the pair delimiters.

```
my $hostname = 'bandit.labs.overthewire.org';
my $username = 'bandit0';
my $password = 'bandit0';
my $port     = 2220;
my $command  = q{};
```

---

> ```
> $user =~ s/(\d+)\z/ $1 + 1 /e;
> ```

This line is fine, but I would like to point out the [`/x` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#*x*-and-*xx*), that allows you to use comments on the pattern part of the substitution. You can also change the delimiter, so this *could* (but in this case should probably not) become:

```
$user =~ s{
    (\d+) # grab lots of numbers
    \z    # at the end of the line
}{ $1 + 1 }ex;
```

---

> ```
> my ($pass, $user, $c) = @_;
> ```

What is `$c`? I guess it is the command, but it's not as nicely verbose as your other variables. I do a lot of work with the Catalyst framework, and to me, `$c` is hardwired to the Catalyst context object. One-letter variable names are seldom the right choice. Always go for clarity.

---

> ```
> my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", port=>$port, debug=>0);
> ```

You do not need to quote variable names. New Perls will probably optimize this away, but it's ugly and might introduce bugs. You've done that a couple of times (though not consistently), and I'm not going to mention it again.

Also, your spacing here is inconsistent. You are using spaces around the equal (`=`), so why not do the same around the *fat comma* (`=>`)?

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($hostname, port => $port, debug => 0);
```

> ```
> my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("$c");
> my $new_pass = $stdout;
> return $new_pass;
> ```

You only need the `$stdout` variable. The other two are discarded, so there's no reason to assign them at all. You can assign things to `undef` in a list context, and those parts of the list on the right hand side will be thrown away.

```
my (undef, $two, undef) = (1, 2, 3);
```

Since you only want the first value, there's no need to even do that. In list context the assignment will start with the right-most values, and all the later elements on the RHS will be discarded if there is nothing to assign them to on the LHS.

The assignment to `$new_pass` is not necessary because you just return that value. I know it has some kind of documentary value, but you can just name your variable like that in the first place. `$stdout` and `$stderr` only need to be named that if you need to distinguish them. But in this case, you don't care how Net::SSH::Perl got your password.

```
my ($new_pass) = $ssh->cmd($c);
return $new_pass;
```

However, you might want to check for errors somehow. Not sure what those commands return. You maybe want to keep `$exit` to look at it.

---

> ```
> my %hash;
> ```

This is a really bad name. The sigil `%` already tells us it's a hash. This is like naming your child *Child*. The hash holds levels and commands. Why not name it `%commands`?

---

> ```
> open CONFIG, "commands.txt" or die;
> while (my $line = <CONFIG>) {
>     # ...
> }
> ```

This is a big one. Don't use glob filehandles. The `CONFIG` thing is global. It's the same everywhere in your program. Even in modules from CPAN. If you were to call some function while that `CONFIG` filehandle is opened, and that module were also using one with the same name, it would interfere with yours. Instead, use a lexical filehandle.

This has the added benefit that you don't have to use `close` explicitly in this case, as the lexical variable will go out of scope at the end of the function call anyway, and thus the filehandle will implicitly be closed.

You also should use the three-argument form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Your two arg without a mode implies reading, which is fine with this fixed string filename here. But what if the name comes from somewhere else? What if it's `|rm -rf /`? Ooops. You just opened a pipe to a command that deleted your harddrive. Bad luck. Instead, always pass the mode as the second argument, and that kind of thing cannot happen.

You do have `or die`, which is good, but your error will be *Died at ...*. That's not very helpful. Instead, at least include the error that was returned by `open`, which is in [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables). Putting the filename in that error message is helpful too.

```
open my $fh, '<', 'commands.txt' or die "Can't open commands.txt: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) { ... }
```

> ```
> my ($lvl, $cmd) = split /\:/, $line;
> ```

The colon `:` is not a meta character in regex. You don't need to escape it.

---

> ```
>  my $bandit_count = scalar(keys %hash);
> ```

You don't need the parentheses here. In fact, you hardly ever need them in Perl, which makes the code read more like English.

And there's the `%hash` again... Actually it's *another* `%hash`. Using the same variable name in an outer and inner scope it not the best idea, as it's ambiguous.

```
my $bandit_count = scalar keys %hash;
```

---

> ```
> while ($bandit_count-- > 0)
> {
> ```

Your style of placing the curlies is inconsistent. Above you had them on the same line as the `while` loop, now they are in the same line. Decide for one.

That loop could be implemented in a lot of ways. Since you don't care about the loop variable, the way you picked is not very Perlish at all. In fact, you're prone to getting an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) (or two?). The `$foo--` [decrement operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) returns the *current value* of the variable, and then reduces it by one. Is that really what you need here?

It would be easier to get rid of the `$bandid_count` variable completely, and simply use a range with a `for` or `foreach` loop. Both are the same syntactically. Some people prefer the short `for`, but I think for the non-C style loop the `foreach` is easier to read.

```
foreach (1 .. keys %commands) {
     # ...    
}
```

You can leave out the [`scalar][9]` here as well, as the [`..` range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) already puts [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) into scalar context.

---

> ```
> print "$username:$password\n";
> ```

Instead of `print` and the newline, you can use [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html), which is shorter and includes the trailing line break. It's included in Perls starting from version 5.10 and needs to be [turned on with `use feature 'say'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-'say'-feature) or a [feature bundle](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#FEATURE-BUNDLES).

---

In total, this code is pretty solid. If you really just started learning, you've done a great job. But then you are probably an experienced developer already, which is worth a lot.

If you wanted to replace the whole `read_file` sub with something more Perlish, you could do this:

```
sub read_file {
    return do {
        open my $fh, '<', 'commands.txt'
            or die "Can't open commands.txt: $!";
        map { chomp; split /:/ } <$fh>;
    };
}
```

The code makes use of a couple of features. The [`do` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) groups a number of statements into one. It's useful to know that every block's return value is always the return value of the last statement. That's also true for subs, so if there is no explicit `return`, chances are something will go wrong at some point.

[`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) is like a `foreach` loop, and you probably know it from other languages that implement the map and reduce pattern. In the block, the topic variable `$_` is used to iterate the list that comes out of the `<$fh>` diamond operator, which will just return the whole file as a list of lines in list context. Both `chomp` and `split` work on `$_` implicitly if no arguments are passed, which makes this really concise.

---

If I may suggest another resource, the book [*Beginning Perl* by Curtis "Ovid" Poe](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Perl.productCd-1118013840.html) is great for developers that want to switch to Perl, as it has a nice walk-through, but does not explain everything down to how programming works, like *Learning Perl* would. To get more of the new stuff that's in the language, take a look at [chromatic's *Modern Perl*](http://modernperlbooks.com/), which is available for free online. Finally, there are some nice tricks in [*Effective Perl* by Joseph N. Hall, Joshua A. McAdams and brian d foy](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Hall-Effective-Perl-Programming-Ways-to-Write-Better-More-Idiomatic-Perl-2nd-Edition/PGM95897.html). Several of the authors of these books are frequent users on Stack Overflow too.

Finally, something that might make your life a bit easier as these challenges get harder is [Object::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Remote). It allows you to execute Perl code on remote systems via SSH, without installing any modules there. You can use everything you have locally as long as it's compatible with the Perl that's there remotely, down to 5.8. [Here is a great talk about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hIyawUrCcQ) by the author from the German Perl Workshop 2014.

Comment: Already some great points. I have one nitpick, the escaping of `:` was not in my original program. But I added it, because the syntax highlighting got all funny without it.

Comment: @Ludisposed I've updated the answer. it's pretty much complete now.

Comment: Thank you for taking effort to point some good reference material. :+1: I find the perl documentation sometimes hard to find.

Comment: @Ludisposed I added some more stuff. / The docs themselves are really good, but you are right that some stuff is tricky to find. `perldoc` and the online search are your friend. You will also find high quality tutorials on www.perlmaven.com. There are a lot more resources linked in the Perl tag wiki on SO. Just be careful not to use old stuff. My rule is that deem any resource as out of date and/or crap if it doesn't have strict and warnings. Btw, [the language is called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name) _Perl_, and the interpreter binary is called _perl_.

Comment: @Ludisposed and one last thing. I see you're in the Netherlands. There are two user groups in Amsterdam. [Amsterdam.pm](http://amsterdam.pm/) is in Dutch, and [AmsterdamX.pm](http://amsterdamx.pm.org/) is in English targeted at Expats, and the German [Niederrhein.pm](https://www.meetup.com/de-DE/NiederrheinPM/) might be close, too. I will be giving a talk next Saturday at the free one-day [London Perl Workshop](http://act.yapc.eu/lpw2017/). You can come say hi and have a pint with some of the Perl tag regulars from Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: I'm  surprised to see you advocate `foreach`, and I would prefer to see `read_file` returning a reference to a hash. There's also no need for the `do` block.

Comment: @Ludisposed: It is a good idea to read [`perlstyle`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) for ideas of what a standard Perl program should look like. Follow that document and most people will be comfortable with your code. `perldoc.perl.org` is also a great source of all the standard Perl documentation which comes with your perl installation. It is indexed and searchable. I would like to see more blank lines in your code, separating the statements into functional groups of one or more.

Comment: @Borodin I think I've improved my style a bit in my new [Perl question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180745/perl-letter-frequency-analysis-breaking-vignere). :)

Comment: @Borodin as I said in the answer, the `for` vs `foreach` thing is really a matter of preference. I know a lot of people think `for` is shorter and thus better. I've had very passionate discussions over beer with PPI's Mithaldu on that matter. But for someone who is learning the language, I think `foreach` feels more natural if they are used to a C style `for` loop. / Regarding the hash reference, yes. I wanted to mention that but forgot. If you look at the edit history you will see I did this in two stages. Needed to go home in between.

Comment: My background is more `Python/Bash`, the quoting of variables was a shocker for me. And the `foreach` feels more natural, like a `for` loop in Python.